# What is the best way to collect thermal data on my Android device?

Tags: android, testing, system, performance-testing

I am trying to collect thermal data on my Android tablet (running Android 9) while running various apps/benchmarks etc. Specifically, I want to be able to both measure and log core CPU temperatures and frequencies while other apps are running on my tablet. I want to collect CPU temps and freq because I want to know the extent of thermal throttling on my device. There are lots of great apps out there but I can't find one that will log information while running a different app (such as the Geekbench Benchmark). Here is what I've tried so far:

1. I have already tried collecting information from the thermal zones in /sys/class/thermal but am unable to make sense of the names the vendor has given (the vendor in my case is MTK).
2. I have tried using CpuFloat. This app provides a nice overlay on the device display and includes all CPU frequencies (updating in real time) as well as the core temp of the processor. The only problem is CpuFloat doesn't log data over time and I have resorted to taking screenshots periodically to track temperatures. This is really tedious though since I have to sit and record temperatures throughout benchmark testing.

I have considered developing an app that tracks this information, but would like to track it through adb or an existing app if possible. Any help/advice would be appreciated!

Here is what I have tried so far (collecting information from thermal zones using  a batch script on Windows 10)

```
@Echo off
Echo.
mkdir core_freq
mkdir core_temp
SET tpath=/sys/devices/system/cpu
:inf_iterate
    SET counter=0
    timeout 1
    Echo Recording Thermal Data...
    adb shell cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone7/temp >> core_temp/cpu_temp.txt
    :Loop

        adb shell cat %tpath%/cpu%counter%/cpufreq/cpuinfo_cur_freq >> core_freq/core_%counter%.txt

        SET /A counter+=1
        if %counter%==4 goto inf_iterate
      goto Loop
```

Comment: Hey welcome to stackoverflow could you provide some sample code?

Comment: Have you checked the options under Developer options to see if any fit for you?

Comment: @MarkCarpenterJr I added some sample code to my original post. It collects core frequencies and core temp and then logs them to the core_freq and core_temp folders.

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos I can usually obtain CPU information from Developer Options (as a CPU usage overlay displaying Unix Load Average), however, this option was removed on Android version 8 and above (my device is Android 9).

Comment: As I've continued to research this issue, it appears that collecting thermal data at the system level (/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone[i]) is the best way. This can be implemented either using a script (such as the one above) or through an Android app. The limitation of using this method is that thermal zones are not standard across hardware platforms. Google does provide the HardwarePropertiesManager class to access hardware information such as CPU/GPU temperatures, fan speeds, etc. However, this class appears to be available only in enterprise mode. If anyone finds a better way please share.

Answer (score 0):

from adb shell I get all temperatures in this way:

```
for a in /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone*/;do echo -n "$(cat $a/type) ";cat $a/temp;done|sort -nk2
```